# Consolidating dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have 3 pandas data frames with matching indices. Some operations have trimmed data frames in different ways (removed rows), so that some indices in one data frame may not exist in the other.

I'd like to consolidate all 3 data frames, so they all contain rows with indices that are present in all 3 of them. How is this achievable?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [3,4,5,6], 'c': [6,7,8,9]})

a = pd.DataFrame(data['a'])
b = pd.DataFrame(data['b'])
c = pd.DataFrame(data['c'])

a = a[a['a'] <= 3]
b = b[b['b'] >= 4]

# some operation here that removes rows that aren't present in all (intersection of all dataframe's indices)

print a
   a
1  2
2  3

print b
   b
1  4
2  5

print c
   c
1  7
2  8
```

### Update

Sorry, I got carried away and forgot what I wanted to achieve when I wrote the examples. The actual intent was to keep the 3 dataframes separate. Apologies for the misleading example (I corrected it now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and pass param `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`, the default type of merge is inner, so only values that exist on both left and right will be merged.

```
In [6]:

a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(c, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[6]:
   a  b  c
1  2  4  7
2  3  5  8

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

To modify the original dataframes so that now only contain the rows that exist in all you can do this:

```
In [12]:

merged = a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(c, left_index=True, right_index=True)
merged
Out[12]:
   a  b  c
1  2  4  7
2  3  5  8
In [14]:

a = a.loc[merged.index]
b = b.loc[merged.index]
c = c.loc[merged.index]
In [15]:

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
   a
1  2
2  3
   b
1  4
2  5
   c
1  7
2  8
```

So we merge all of them on index values that are present in all of them and then use the index to filter the original dataframes.

Comment: Merge seems like an interesting alternative to concat. When do you use one or the other? It seems `merge` is more versatile. I updated my post. The way I framed it wasn't what I was actually looking for...

Comment: @orange the original dataframes are not touched here unless you pass param `inplace=True` so a copy is returned

Comment: Sorry, if it's still not clear. I'd actually like to change the original dataframes (or have copies of them). They should only contain those rows whose indices are present in _all_ 3 dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects), which can be used for a variety of combination operations.  Here you want to have the `join` type set to inner (because the want the intersection), and `axis` set to 1 (combining columns).

```
In [123]: pd.concat([a,b,c], join='inner', axis=1)
Out[123]: 
   a  b  c
1  2  4  7
2  3  5  8
```

Comment: Interestingly `merge` is faster for larger dataframes than concat, I compared concat with merge on a 40000 row dataframe and saw this `100 loops, best of 3: 6.3 ms per loop`
`100 loops, best of 3: 4.87 ms per loop` when comparing concat with merge

Comment: Also still faster using a 4 million row dataframe :`1 loops, best of 3: 694 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 494 ms per loop`, this was done using pandas `0.14.0`

Comment: Concat works great. Is there any way the 3 dataframes could be kept separate? Sorry, I messed up the example.